# Markov Chain for Amino Acid Sequence

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, markov-process

I was wondering if it is possible to apply Markov Chain to this amino acid sequence "ddvlsldeddddsdyncgednd" to find the probability of this sequence forming in this particular positional order, given that I already calculated the conditional probability of amino acid B coming next given that amino acid A comes before it in this particular sequence.

for example, I have calculated:

P(D coming next|D came before it)

P(v coming next|D came before it)

P(l coming next|v came before it)
.

.

.

.

P(D coming next|N came before it)

Therefore, I would then do the Markov chain calculation to be something like this:

P("ddvlsldeddddsdyncgednd")=P(D|D) * P(V|D) * P(L|V) * ..... * P(D|N)

Comment: You can return an estimate of the Markov chain transition matrix on the amino acid space but with such a short chain, it will be highly variable.

Comment: If you’ve already computed those conditional probabilities from a larger dataset, this is fine. Remember to end the chain with p(STOP \mid D), the probability of the sequence ending there. Otherwise, you’re finding the total probability of all sequences that start with “ddvlsldeddddsdyncgednd”.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy What if the larger dataset that I have right now are highly biased toward a certain group of amino acids, but I want to calculate the probability of "ddvlsldeddddsdyncgednd" occurring in that positional order due to random occurrence of amino acids?

Comment: You can’t get something for nothing in statistics. Either you have to assume that your training dataset is representative of the sequences you’ll be scoring, or you have to collect more representative data.